# What is the way to get received data out of URLSession?

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

Recently, I attempted to write my own [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). However, the project has seem to have hit a brick wall with URLSession (formerly NSURLSession) issues.

The call structure is as follows:

`getMe() -> getData() -> NSURLSession`

Ideally, I would like to have the data returned from `NSURLSession` passed back to `getMe()` for the application to process. However, this has not proven possible with the methods I have tried.

Below is the code I have been using. `synthesiseURL()` generates the URL that the app should open the session to in order to perform the action on the Telegram Bot API. A template of the URL generated by `synthesiseURL()` is `https://api.telegram.org/bot\(token)/\(tgMethod)`.

```
// NSURLSession getData: gets data from Telegram Bot API
func getData(tgMethod: String, arguments: [String] = [String](), caller: String = #function) {
    let url = synthesiseURL(tgMethod: "getMe"), request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)

    var receivedData = String()

    let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, err in

        if err != nil {print(err!.localizedDescription); return}

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            receivedData = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)!
            print(receivedData)
        }
    }

    session.resume()
}
```

I have been trying to get `getData` to pass `receivedData`, which contains the Bot API's response, back to the function `getMe`.

```
func getMe() -> String {
    HTTPInterface(botToken: token).get(tgMethod: "getMe")
    return [???] // here's where the data from getData() should come
}
```

I have tried completion handlers, callbacks, asynchronous calls to the main thread etc, but none seem to be working as expected (`getMe()` returns an empty string).

Why is this so, and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue is that your `getMe()` function is declared as having an immediate `String` return type, but it depends on a delayed / asynchronous call to get that string.  The timeline looks something like this:

1. `getMe()` is called by some client code
2. `getMe()` kicks of the method that launches a `URLSession` to get the data
3. `getMe()` moves to the next line of execution and returns a string (still empty at this point). The `getMe()` function has now returned and the client code execution has continued forward with the empty `String` result
4. The `URLSession` completes with data, but execution has already moved on so the data doesn't get used anywhere

The easiest fix is to make your `getMe` function not have a return type, but to also call back to a closure parameter when the URLSession data comes back, something like:

```
func getMe(callback:String->()) {
     //getData and pass a closure that executes the callback closure with the String data that comes back
}
```

The less easy fix is to use a technique like dispatch semaphores to prevent `getMe()` from returning a result until the URLSession data comes back. But this sort of approach is likely to stall your main thread and is unlikely to be the right choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regarding the closure you suggested, how should I take this data and process it on the main thread? Would it be possible to have the data passed to `getMe()` for `getMe()` to use as a return value?

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry  You could use something like dispatch semaphores inside your `getMe()` function to force execution to pause until `getMe()` gets an answer from the URLSession, and then use that answer as a return value.  However, this is likely to block the main thread and freeze the UI until the response comes back (bad idea). The best way is to have whatever code that calls `getMe()` pass in a closure that should be executed with the String result when `getMe()` eventually asynchronously completes, and not expect an immediate return from the `getMe()` function.

Comment: I see. In that sense I think I'll go with the asynchronous completion handler. Thanks for your help!